# How does 'eclipse' cmd in Linux map to an eclipse installation?

Tags: linux, eclipse, command-line

I am on Ubuntu and I am trying to upgrade from eclipse 3.5 to eclipse 3.7. I want to preserve the 3.5 version of eclipse and just work out of 3.7.

When I type "eclipse" on the command line, the old version of eclipse is launched. The "eclipse" command doesn't appear to be defined in my PATH. How does Linux create a mapping from this command to the eclipse installation? I would like to change the mapping so that it launches 3.7 instead.

```
wsl:~$ cat ~/.bashrc | egrep 'eclpse|ECLIPSE|Eclipse'
```

`wsl:~$ echo $PATH | egrep 'eclipse|ECLIPSE|Eclipse'`

`wsl:~$`

Comment: will the "eclipse" cmd always go look in /usr/bin? That is where it is launching eclipse from right now.

Comment: The shell will search all directories in `$PATH`, left to right, and pick the first `eclipse` it finds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `which eclipse` to display the full path of the executable; that directory must be in your `PATH`.

Comment: i've checked a few times; it's definitely not in my path.


wsl:~$ cat ~/.bashrc | egrep 'eclpse|ECLIPSE|Eclipse'
wsl:~$ echo $PATH | egrep 'eclipse|ECLIPSE|Eclipse'
wsl:~$

Comment: `eclipse` itself won't be in PATH, but the directory it resides in will be. Use `which` to find out which path that is.

Answer (score 1):

check your ".bashrc" for "$ECLIPSE_HOME/"